# Sql syntax issue with adding values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an error in my sql on second addSql() line:

```php
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, `key` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, value VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_E545A0C58A90ABA9 (`key`), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');

$this->addSql("INSERT INTO user (id,key,value) VALUES (1,'theKey','14')");
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,value) VALUES (1,'theKey','14')' at line 1

Can someone help to locate it..

Comment: Do not supply the name/value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column btw.

Comment: You need backticks around the column name `key`, same as you have in the first statement. It's a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

The 'key` word is reserved word in MySQL. I advice to avoid using reserved as column names. Any way is it necessary use backticks to quote them:

```php
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, `key` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, `value` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_E545A0C58A90ABA9 (`key`), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');

$this->addSql("INSERT INTO user (`id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (1,'theKey','14')");
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=b39c5914c45c07fd5f3daae1607dbe9d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Great! This did it. Thank you. :) @SlavaRozhnev

Answer (score 0):

changing `VALUE` to `VALUES` should do the trick

Comment: I have. Same error. @AndrewEdgar